# Where do vegan animals get their b12 if not from vegetation?

Tags: veganism, health, b12

If vitamin b12 is in meat and dairy, then where do the animals get their b12 from?

According to nutritionists, eating [dead animals](https://fdc.nal.usda.gov/fdc-app.html#/food-details/746763/nutrients) and animal derivatives (eg [milk](https://fdc.nal.usda.gov/fdc-app.html#/food-details/746782/nutrients)) provides some amount of vitamin b12.

However, it's not clear to me how these animals have b12 in their bodies.

How do animals like cows get vitamin b12 in their bodies?

Comment: From the intestinal bacteria as answered on [Biology SE](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/35786/why-do-humans-require-vitamin-b12-supplementation-while-herbivores-do-not).